# In 14.04 ubuntu should there be in the application menu-system some kind of scanner setting?

Tags: drivers, 14.04, scanner

I can't get the computer to see a scanner when it boots up. It's a dual boot in XP and Scanner works fine in XP.

canoscan 5600F

Bios = Phoenix Tech ver. 6.00PG

MB = Via Tech Inc. PM800 8237

Intel Celeron 2.93GHz

Comment: @ user 68186 and girardengo: Thanks for the help. Simple scan is installed but is not detecting a scanner (in a bold red banner). I un-plugged and re-plugged both USB and power cords but computer won't see the Canoscan 5600F in UBUNTU but does find the scanner in XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this scanner has no drivers for Linux provided by Canon. See 
http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/P/search?category=Scanners&series=CanoScan&model=CanoScan+5600F&menu=Download&filter=0

The SANE backend (that works behind Simple Scan) also does not seem to support this scanner. Scroll down the official SANE list http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON

Hope this helps

Comment: vote up

Privilege type: Moderation privilege

Awarded at: 15 reputation